# fail2ban is not sending mail when it bans an ip!

Tags: configuration, security, mail, iptables, fail2ban

I have configured fail2ban to send me a mail when it bans an IP, but it is not working. I get a message when the jails start and stop but nothing else .
I am using ssmtp to send mail via Google Mail.

This is my [jail.local](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1093057/).

Comment: Please revise your post to reduce the font size of your config file, try to use use block quote or code sample by pressing Ctrl+Q or Ctrl+K

Comment: Sorry. It's okay now .

Comment: Did you check the log file (`/var/log/fail2ban.log`) for possible errors?

Comment: That was an issue with the server company . Thanks

Comment: jail.local is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the jail.conf file Look for the line:

```
action = %(action_)s
```

and change it to

```
action = %(action_mwl)s
```

or

```
action = %(action_mw)s
```

Comment: http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=45597